# Should there be one or two periods in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I would like to know which of these sentences is preferable:

1. Nietzsche said: "If you gaze long into an abyss, the abyss also gazes into you." (Beyond Good and Evil, Aphorism 146).
2. Nietzsche said: "If you gaze long into an abyss, the abyss also gazes into you" (Beyond Good and Evil, Aphorism 146).

In other words, should there be one period at the end of the quote and another period at the end of the parenthesis, or only one period (at the end of the parenthesis)?

Comment: Period follows a sentence/ independent clause. Here, //(Beyond Good and Evil, Aphorism 146).// is neither; hence period is not required.

Comment: So which sentence should one use? The first or the second?

Comment: If I were, I would write, //Nietzsche said: "If you gaze long into an abyss, the abyss also gazes into you." (Beyond Good and Evil, Aphorism 146)